# Do all matrices with a 0 limit decrease?

Tags: matrices

Given a matrix A, Does
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}A^n=0$$
Imply that(by lower then I mean that every number in the lower matrix is closer or the same distance to 0 then it’s counterpart in the bigger one)
$$\text{if }a>b>0 \text{ then }A^a<A^b$$
In R it’s true, a Number who is in between -1 and 1 is always getting closer to 0 and never goes up and back down.
I’m unsure of it’s truth for matrices especially with my definition.
Can any of you provide hints/proves for it?
Maybe counter example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In matrix what do you mean by $>$ operator. If you want to define an order relationship you should at least define that is the order relationship.

Comment: For instance, I was thinking that by $X>Y$ you meant $$\forall i,\forall j, \lvert X_{ij}\rvert>\lvert Y_{ij}\rvert$$ which has the remarkable feature of not agreeing with the $>$ of $\Bbb R$. However, then I cannot quite make sense of your $a>b\Rightarrow A^a>A^b$, as I would have assumed $a<b\Rightarrow A^a>A^b$ to be a more sensible guess (still false, I think).

Comment: yes, wrote it wrong.

Comment: I don't think there is any order on matrices algebra that respects the product (maybe I'm wrong), so I don't understand what could be your question.

Comment: it's not suppose to be an ordering of matrices, instead trying to reflect a propriety of multiplication in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Consider:
$$ A :=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0.5 \\
0.5 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then the sequence of matrix is as follows:
\begin{align*}
A^2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0.25 & 0 \\
0 & 0.25
\end{pmatrix}, \;
A^3 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0.125 \\
0.125 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \;
A^4 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0.0625 & 0 \\
0 & 0.0625
\end{pmatrix}, \;
\dots
\end{align*}
which tends to $0$ (under any norm), but $A^2 \not< A$ (under your definition of $<$).

Comment: yes, but i find it rather trivial, maybe i should have specified that it's staying the same also works.

Comment: fixed the question.

Comment: @razivo what do you mean? The $(1,1)$-entry of $A^2$ is strictly bigger than that of $A$.

Comment: Very sorry, saw it flipped right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A=e^{u}\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha&-\sin\alpha\\ \sin\alpha&\cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}$, which we'll call $A(u,\alpha)$. Such matrices have the property that $(A(u,\alpha))^n=A(nu,n\alpha)$ and $\sqrt{ \operatorname{tr}((A(u,\alpha))^tA(u,\alpha))}=\sqrt2e^u$. Select $\alpha>0$ small enough so that $k\alpha\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$ for all $1\le k\le N$. We have that $\lvert A(ku,k\alpha )_{2,1}\rvert=e^{ku}\lvert\sin(k\alpha)\rvert$, and therefore, for all $1\le m<n\le N$, $$\lvert A(nu,n\alpha)_{2,1}\rvert<\lvert A(mu,m\alpha)_{2,1}\rvert\iff u<\frac1{n-m}\ln\frac{\sin(m\alpha)}{\sin(n\alpha)}$$

Notice that the hypothesis on $\alpha$, $m$ and $n$ guarantee that $\sin(m\alpha)<\sin(n\alpha)$ for all $1\le m<n\le N$, so that the $\ln$ on the RHS is negative.

Therefore, if you fix a positive integer $N$, an angle $\alpha\in\left(0,\frac\pi{2N}\right)$ and some $u$ such that $\max\limits_{1\le m<n\le N} \frac1{n-m}\ln\frac{\sin(m\alpha)}{\sin(n\alpha)}< u<0$, then you'll have that $(A(u,\alpha))^m>(A(u,\alpha))^n$ fails for all $1\le m<n\le N$.